# problem with setting & accessing a variable value in django template

Tags: python, django, templates

I want to set a variable `err` for errors in the form fields (using *django 2.1.3*):

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% if field.errors %}
        {% with field.errors as err %}{% endwith %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}


{% if err %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger fade show">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
           aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        {{ err }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

But, while rendering to html the value of the variable has no output. Though, there are errors, which I've raised using `forms.ValidationError`.

Also, try this like ...

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% if field.errors %}
        <div ... >
            ...
            ...
            {{ field.errors }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

In this case, output or the errors are showing, but with multiple `<div>` elements & **n** no. of times.
I know that, it can be done by another way in the `views.py`: using *'django.contrib.messages'*. Then sending errors to *messages.error()*, inside `form.is_valid()`, then ...

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {{ message }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But, I want to manipulate it from `forms.py` file. So, how do I do it?
️️️️
**Thanks in advance!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of a `with` statement is until the matching `endwith`. Your endwidth is immediately after the with, so the variable exists for no time at all.

Even if this worked, you only define a single `err` anyway; if there are multiple errors it would only have the value of the last one, which defeats the whole purpose of what you are trying to do.

You should not use contrib.messages for this. You should use the errors from the *form*, not from the field.

```
{% if form.errors %}
    <div ... >
        ...
        ...
        {% for error in form.errors %}
        {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Note you can further customise the way errors are displayed by defining an [ErrorList subclass](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#customizing-the-error-list-format).

Comment: Working partially, I mean to say it shows the fields where the error is occurred. And, by putting: `{% for field in form %}{{ field.errors }}{% endfor %}` within that _IF Statement_, I got the exact output, with error statement. Thanks! ️ @Daniel